# Закрыть вкладку

Tags: jquery

Возможно ли каким-нибудь способом на  JQuery закрыть текущую вкладку в браузере при нажатии на ссылку?

Comment: Нельзя. В целях безопасности.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close